Не работают инлайн кнопки бота в запланированном сообщении
пишу телеграм бота на aiogram:
async def some_func():
    err = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    btn_1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='open_1', callback_data='number_1')
    btn_2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='open_2', callback_data='number_2')
    err.add(btn_1, btn_2)
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text='choose:', reply_markup=err)

есть хэндлер сообщений:
@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith=['number_'])
async def number(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery)
    variant = callback_query.data.split("_")
    if variant[1] == 1:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text='number_1'
    else:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text='number_2'

функция запускается по расписанию:
async def scheduler():
    aioschedule.every().day.at("20:39").do(some_func)
    while True:
        await aioschedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def on_startup(_):
    await asyncio.create_task(scheduler())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)

почему не происходит перехват callback_data? что не так я делаю?

@Andrey тут до этого не доходит, почему то при нажатии на кнопку с выбором ТГ пишет Loading и ничего не происходит, не похоже, что дело в типе данных, мне кажется, что то с асинхронностью

Самое простое - это воспользоваться print'ами, сразу будет видна ошибка

по нажатию на кнопку     btn_2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='open_2', callback_data='number_2')
как посмотреть что она она передает?

Под строкой пишете print() и передаете объект, с которым кнопка работает. В консоле результат

Попробуйте так:
@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith=['number_'])
async def number(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    variant = callback_query.data.split("_")
    if variant[1] == '1':
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text='number_1')
    else:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text='number_2')

Исправления:

Добавлена закрывающая скобка после аргумента text в вызове bot.send_message.
Добавлены кавычки вокруг значения '1' в условии if variant[1] == '1':, чтобы сравнение выполнялось с правильным типом данных.

Просто будьте внимательнее и проверяйте код)
